# Content Import error - Server Error 500

Tags: 2sxc

After many months of using 2sxc; building sites, importing content, without any problems, I'm encountering an issue when importing content to a new site. The only error message I see is "Had an error talking to the server (status 500)." If I use a Content export from a previous date, the import works fine.  This happens in multiple portals on the same server, and on both my production and testing servers.  Almost seems like a corrupt export file, but all repeated exports I've tried have the same problem.

F12-console doesn't reveal much, but I've attached the .log export. There is nothing in the Admin Events Viewer related to 2SXC, and nothing in the server event viewer either.

Developer Console log export:  https://gotrwebsite.s3.amazonaws.com/pintiva.biz-1485972308931.log

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log it appears that something is wrong with routing. I'm assuming this, because your error is deliver as HTML, which is not what APIs should deliver - these usually give a JSON error.

What appears to be happening here is that the API-URL seems to be regarded an a normal page-url, so to 90% probablity the import doesn't even get triggered, but DNN processes the request - and fails then.

The cause for this is hard to guess - but it's often that your DNN setup has some incorrect URLs registered for this portal, making it "ignore" the routes, because it assumes this isn't part of the normal request. Could this be the case?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if this is the case.  Is there a specific page URL I should be looking for that would conflict with the API URL?

Comment: I can't give a quick answer to that. But best check the site-settings to verify that the primary urls and alternate urls are all correct. If that is the case, it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Seven years later... The cause of a similar issue on my server was good old maxRequestLength="29296" in web.config.  That number is in kilobytes. My apps export grew well beyond that.  So I changed that param temporarily to maxRequestLength="400000".  That solved the issue for me.